# Finding the order of $\,[2]\,$ in $\;\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find the order of $[2]$ in $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ where:

$\begin{align} (i) \;m & = 11 \\ \\
(ii)\;\; m & = 17 \\ \\
(iii)\;\; m & = 31 \\ \\
(iv)\;\; m & = 9 \\ \\ 
(v)\;\; m & = 14 
\end{align}$

I can not seem to understand how to do this.

Could I see an example of $m = 11$, and then I can try others for myself.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Z} = m\mathbb{Z}$? Do you mean to ask to find the order of the equivalence class of $[2]$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

Comment: I edited the question to improve the formatting, and I changed $\Bbb Z = m\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$. If this is not what you intended, please change the question to what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\quad \gcd(2, 11) = 1$. Indeed, *every element* in $\mathbb Z_{11}$, except for $[0]$, the identity, is relatively prime to $11$, since $11$ is prime, and hence, has every element except for $[0]$ has $\;\bf \text{order} \;11$

This is, of course, assuming you mean $\mathbb Z_{11}$, or $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$, the group of integers modulo under addition modulo $11$.

---

If, however, you mean to ask about the order of elements in *multiplicative groups*  $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, then you first need to compute the *order* of the groups for the respective $m$-values. In general, the multiplicative group consists of all integers $[k]$, $1 \leq  k \lt m$ that are *relatively prime* to $m.$ The number of such elements, of course, is the order of the group, and is given by $\phi(m)$.  For example, the order of any such group, when $m$ is prime, is equal to $m - 1$.

So the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$ has order $10$. Now, the order of any element in any group is equal to the order of the group generated by the element. By the Theorem of Lagrange, we know that the order of any subgroup of a group of finite order divides the order of the group. So, there are $4$ possibilities for the order of $[2]$: $1, 2, 5, 10$. The only group of order 1, of course, is the multiplicative identity, 1. So you simply need to determine the order of $[2]$ by determining the order of the subgroup of $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I assumed that the question referred to the *multiplicative* order, but I realize that your interpretation is equally valid.

Comment: @Lubin: Thank you for commenting. I expanded a bit to touch on that possibility: that the question concerns the multiplicative order of an element in the *multiplicative group* $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
[2]\neq [0] & \implies \text{order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ is not }1\\[0.1in]
[2]+[2]=[4]\neq [0] & \implies \text{order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ is not }2\\
&\quad\vdots\\
\underbrace{[2]+\cdots+[2]}_{10\text{ times}}=[20]\neq [0] & \implies \text{order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ is not }10\\[0.2in]
\underbrace{[2]+\cdots+[2]}_{11\text{ times}}=[22]=[0] & \implies \text{order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ }\;\textbf{ IS }\;11\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I think started to see how this works. can you check m = 17 [2] $\ne$ [0] ==> order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}$/17 $\mathbb{Z}$ is not 1 [4] $\ne$ [0] ==> order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}$/17 $\mathbb{Z}$ is not 2 ... [34] = [0] ==> order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}$ 17/ $\mathbb{Z}$ is 17 so final answer is " [34] = [0] ==> order of [2] in $\mathbb{Z}$ 17/ $\mathbb{Z}$ is 17"? if this the case than: order of [2] is in $\mathbb{Z}$ 31/ $\mathbb{Z}$ is 31. order of [2] is in $\mathbb{Z}$ /9 $\mathbb{Z}$ is 9. and so on...